# /feed connection inconsistent with /statuses?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, status, privacy

I asked a [question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10894414/getting-the-privacy-setting-of-a-status-message) a couple of days ago regarding getting privacy information for people's status updates. I was then advised to use the **/feed** connection instead of **/statuses** so I could access the `privacy` attribute.

After re-working our app, I've noticed that **/feed** only appears to return status updates from around the 20th of January 2011. Comments, wall posts and so on, on the other hand, are returned since the user registered with Facebook.
Initially I thought this might have been a quirk on my profile for some reason, but a number of different developers of our app have been able to replicate the same result.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening, or know of a way to retrieve **all** of a user's statuses along with their associated privacy information?

**Edit:** I should add that I'm able to retrieve all statuses just fine using the **/statuses** connection, but this isn't ideal as we **need** access to the `privacy` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the official [How-To: Paging with the Graph API and FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/) post?

It describes fields such as offset, since and until to let you control the span of time for the data you request.
For example here's the feed of the logged in user from `Sat, 07 Jun 2008 12:16:39 GMT` until `Mon, 07 Jun 2010 12:16:39 GMT` in the [graph explorer tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/feed%3Fsince%3D1212840999%26until%3D1275912999).

Comment: Yes I have. Like I said, I'm able to page all the way through till the end of the feed. (I know this because I can see the first ever posts on my wall, for example)
The issue I'm having is that **status updates** stop appearing from around the 20th of January 2011.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that part..  Well, seems like you're right. But even with the `statuses` connection I can't seem to get older results...

Comment: Odd... I'm able to get them all on `/statuses` by iterating through them using the `limit` and `offset` parameters. They don't seem to work very well with `/feed` though. (After the first page no data is returned)

Comment: I get empty data (`data: []`) for `me/statuses` after a certain time (and I checked and do have statuses from then)

Comment: I've reported this as a bug on Facebook, as I'm pretty sure we should be able to access all status updates using either connection. (Unless I'm mistaken, or unless they purposefully don't allow access to older for some reason)
Hopefully they'll acknowledge it soon.
Regardless, it's still odd that you can't access all your statuses after a certain time, and I can get all of mine using the same connection...